# Get Duration of Streamed Audio file in [just-audio] Flutter Plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, audio-streaming, just-audio

I'm using Flutter's Just-Audio plugin to play audio from the web. As I need to use Just-Audio's clipping function to remove a tiny bit of audio off the end, I need to get the duration of the file.

```
ClippingAudioSource(
      start: Duration(seconds: 0),
      end: Duration(milliseconds: duration-of-file-minus-500-milliseconds),
      child: AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
          "https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myaudio.mp3")),
    ),
```

So how can I get this figure for "duration-of-file-minus-500-milliseconds"? I'm using AWS S3 buckets so can I maybe do something with metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You can get duration of audio like this

```
Duration _duration = await _audioPlayer.setUrl('audio_url');
```

And you can use `setClip` method of [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) plugin

```
await _audioPlayer.setClip(start: Duration(seconds: 10), end: Duration(seconds: 20));
await _audioPlayer.play(); // Waits until the clip has finished playing
```

Comment: I'm not clear on how this is supposed to get the duration of the audio file from the web?

Comment: I put that new line under; class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> but got the error ; A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Duration'.

Comment: I've also just realized its asynchronous so I created a Future but still got the same error.  Future<void> getDuration(int audiotime) async { Duration _duration = await _player.setUrl('audio_url');}

Comment: if you want to use function then use like this Future<Duration> getDuration() async {
    final Duration _duration = await _audioPlayer.setUrl('audio_url');
    return _duration;
  }, otherwise the single line Duration _duration = await _audioPlayer.setUrl('audio_url'); will also work. Both are same. They both are return Duration value of audio

Comment: This "Duration value of audio" doesn't seem to give me the integer I wanted for this;   end: Duration(milliseconds: duration-of-file minus 500ms)?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused because the code from the example I'm using uses a playlist. But I just need to play one mp3 and need the duration of that streaming mp3 so that I can clip 500ms off the end.

Comment: Duration also has it's own property inMilliseconds, change you function according like this.   Future<int> getDuration(int audiotime) async {
    final Duration _duration = await _audioPlayer.setUrl('audio_url');
    return _duration.inMilliseconds;
  } or you can direct use end: _duration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232542/discussion-between-meggy-and-hemal-moradiya).

Comment: alway return null on flutter.

Comment: In android just_audio gives correct duration but in iOS the duration is not correct. It's always at least 4 seconds more than real duration in iOS. Is there anything I have to do in iOS to get correct duration?